# Gravity and Teleportation in fly mode

Tags: interface, 3d-view

When I press shift + f and enter fly mode, while flying around my scene, I noticed pressing tab doesn't toggle gravity, and when I press space I don't teleport either. Is there a user preference or something that I am missing?

Comment: All user preferences should be located in the User Preferences window (Ctrl+Alt+U to open).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those shortcuts apply to Walk Mode not fly mode. Make sure you are in the correct mode.

see https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/dev/editors/3dview/navigate/walk_fly.html

Comment: The shortcut for them is the same, mode which will be turned on should be choosed from User Prefs.